# List items not visible when grouped by drop down choice

Tags: list, view, grouping

[image: list ungrouped]

When I group the above list by the Status field the list items are not visible. If I group by a different field, the groups work correctly

[image]

Comment: should you share the setting of your list , also please what's the type of status field ?

Comment: Status is a choice field (drop-down menu). I don't understand your other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown choice had a tab and that's why it didn't work.

Changing the statuses from "1. Name" to "1.Name" meant the view worked

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand the result (Status column) and show how the list items are not visible? In the above screen shot each result row has the count and when you expand it, it will show the actual list items.

Comment: They are expanded in the screenshot